# Unknown bson type DECIMAL128 in when show on template client?

Tags: mongodb, vue.js, meteor, aggregate

I user find for meteor and aggregate I try to get data form server I test both of them it work but, I get trouble when I use
**.toNumber()** function with aggregate that data type amount is Decimal in mongodb. I am not sure to get data to show on client in template. any suggestion Please help me 
My Code collection Schema

Collection schema (SimpleSchema)

```
amount: {
  type: Object, // I tried use `Decimal`
  blackbox: true,
},
```

Method on server sample it work find after insert amount store in data type **Decimal** and get data both with findOne abd aggregate

```
import { Decimal } from 'meteor/mongo-decimal'
Meteor.methods({
   insert(){
     return Collection.insert({amount: Decimal(0.123)})
   },
   findOne(){
     return Collection.findOne({})
   },
   aggregate(){
     return Collection.aggregate([{ $limit: 1 }])[0] // sakulstra:aggregate
   }
 })
```

Get data in Client when get with findOne .toNumber() it work fine but when I use with aggregate .toNumber() it unknown.
So during find query I am getting Unknown bson type DECIMAL128

```
Meteor.call('findOne', (err, res)=>{
    res.amount.toNumber() // Work fine with Decimal JS method
})     
 Meteor.call('aggregate', (err, res)=>{
    res.amount.toNumber() // don't work with Decimal JS method
})
```

Comment: Your version of MongoDB predates 3.4 which introduces the Decimal 128 type for Aggregate type functions.

Comment: my Mongo version 4

Comment: any suggestion please